# Can't run composer command programmatically in magento 2

Tags: magento2, composer, shell

I am using php shell_exec method to run the magento commands in my controller.

Below is my controller code.

```
<?php 
 namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Migrate;
 use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
 class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
 protected $resultPageFactory;
 protected $migrationHelper;
 protected $logger;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    LoggerInterface $logger
) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * Execute view action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
 */
public function execute()
{
    
    $commandCache = "php bin/magento cache:enable";
    shell_exec($commandCache); 
    
    try{
        $m2version = 2.3.4;
        $commandRepo = "composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com";
        $this->logger->info('--commandRepo--'.$commandRepo);
        shell_exec($commandRepo);           
        $commandVersion = "composer require magento/data-migration-tool:".$m2version;
        shell_exec($commandVersion);
        
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        $this->logger->info('--exception--'.json_encode($e->getMessage()));
    }
  }
}
```

In the above code, cache enable command is working, but I am downloading data-migration tool using composer, but that command is not working, if I run the command manually in shell prompt, its working.

Is there anything else I have to make change?

Can someone please help me on this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please also mention what you changed .. also post your code here.

Comment: @lalitmohan, could you check what is the issue?

Comment: Have you found the solution for it?

Comment: Hi @jafarpinjar
I think you may need to pass public and private key as Magento requires it while doing this.

Comment: or you can create auth.json file on root with public and private key then see how it goes. I am not sure about this solution

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar, auth.json file present in root already, same command if i run from shell, its working, programmatically its not working in my controller file

Comment: I feel it's not coming in picture in your case

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar, not cleared with your comment. pls explain briefly

Comment: what happens if you wrap the version with double quotes?

Comment: @fmsthird, yes same even enclosed version in double quotes, all other commands are working apart from the composer commands.

Comment: no logs or anything? it might be that the composer path is needed also to run the composer command properly

Comment: @fmsthird, yes i tried to give composer path like this in execute function, putenv('COMPOSER_HOME= /usr/local/bin/composer');, but no luck, no logs also

Comment: maybe try to play around on the path, like try to insert the exact path without using putenv and etc.. just a `/usr/local/bin/composer` or `exact_composer_path/composer`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117080/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-fmsthird).

Comment: @fmsthird  any idea how to include path without using putenv, I am not cleared about it

Comment: Are you sure you have increased (enough) `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time`? 
Something in php/apache/nginx error log?

Comment: @Bashev, yes all server settings are fine, but the command itself not executing.. there is no error logs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Step 1:
Run `which composer` command directly on shell. You'll get something like

```
/usr/local/bin/composer
```

Step 2:
In your controller code replace your `composer require ...` command with this one

```
cd /root/folder/of/magento && php -dmemory_limit=2G /usr/local/bin/composer require //package
```

If this doesn't work than I am afraid you might have to give your vendor folder permissions of 755 or 777 which is quiet risky.

Comment: hello @Arbab, nope same issue, its not working!

Comment: @jafarpinjar edited my 2nd command try this out